# Implementing a mini shell in C - Issues with Background Processes and SIGCHILD Signal

Tags: c, shell, background-process

I am currently working on building a mini shell in C with basic functionalities like pipeline redirection, input/output handling, etc. I've encountered an issue that I've managed to solve, but the solutions are not entirely clear to me.

**Problem :** Head of Background Processes LinkedList Resets to NULL

Here is the code I wrote:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "variante.h"
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include "readcmd.h"
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

struct background_processes {
    int pid;
    char* cmd_name;
    struct background_processes* next;
};

struct background_processes* head = NULL;

void add_background_process(int pid, char* name) {
    if (head == NULL) {
        head = malloc(sizeof(struct background_processes));
        if (head == NULL) {
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        head->pid = pid;
        head->cmd_name = name;
        head->next = NULL;
    } else {
        struct background_processes* current = head;
        while (current->next != NULL) {
            current = current->next;
        }
        current->next = malloc(sizeof(struct background_processes));
        if (current->next == NULL)
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        current->next->pid = pid;
        current->next->cmd_name = name;
        current->next->next = NULL;
    }
}


void execute_pipeline(struct cmdline* l) {
    int previous_pipe_read = -1;
    int file_descriptor[2];
    for (size_t i = 0; l->seq[i] != 0; i++) {
        pipe(file_descriptor);

        pid_t child_pid = fork();
        char** cmd = l->seq[i];

        if (child_pid == -1) {
            perror("fork error");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        if (child_pid == 0) {
            // Child process

            // other code

            if (strcmp(cmd[0], "jobs") == 0) {
                // Handle jobs command
            }
              
            // other code

            execute_single_command(cmd);
        } else {
            // Parent process
            if (!l->bg) {
                int status;
                waitpid(child_pid, &status, 0);
            } else {
                // <------------PROBLEM ------------->
                add_background_process(child_pid, cmd[0]);
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    printf("Variante %d\n", VARIANTE);

    while (1) {
        struct cmdline* l;
        char* line = 0;
        char* prompt = "ensishell>";

        line = readline(prompt);
        if (line == 0 || !strncmp(line, "exit", 4)) {
            free(line);
            exit(0);
        }

        l = parsecmd(&line);

        if (!l) {
            free(line);
            exit(0);
        }

        if (l->err) {
            printf("error: %s\n", l->err);
            continue;
        }

        if (l->in)
            printf("in: %s\n", l->in);
        if (l->out)
            printf("out: %s\n", l->out);
        if (l->bg)
            printf("background (&)\n");

        execute_pipeline(l);
    }
    free(head);
}
```

I have a method add_background_process intended to add a background process to a linked list. However, when I place this method in the child process, I observe that the head of the linked list is always resetting to NULL. I'm struggling to understand why this is happening. Any insights or suggestions on how to fix this issue?

I appreciate any help or guidance you can provide. If additional information or code snippets are needed, please let me know. Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: Aside: `exit(0)` signals a successful termination. Perhaps you meant to write `exit(EXIT_FAILURE)`?